# AccessControlException with xmlparserv2.jar in Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, xsd, xml-parsing, websphere, websphere-8

I have added xmlparserv2.jar in server.xml and restarted the server. But at start of websphere 8.5.5, I am getting the below error results server is failed to start. When i removed the above jar entry, server is working fine as expected. I just want to know any compatibility issues with this jar and WAS version 8.5.5. If dont place the jar file, i am getting application specific error like org.apache.xml.parser ClassNotFoundExceptions. Thanks in advance

I have restarted the server and also mahcine to check any kind of file lock but even after restarts of respective approaches, i am getting this error.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\config\cells\WIN-COSA3MGR20ONode01Cell\nodes\WIN-COSA3MGR20ONode01\servers\server1\server.xml read)
at java.security.AccessController.throwACE(AccessController.java:100)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:174)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:544)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:883)
at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:763)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:77)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:173)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1022)
at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.openURL(XMLReader.java:2078)
```

Code where i am getting the error :

```
public static Document validateXMLSchema(Reader in)
    throws XMLParseException, Exception
{
    DOMParser dp = new DOMParser();
    dp.setValidationMode(3);
    dp.setPreserveWhitespace(true);
    dp.parse(in);
    return dp.getDocument();
}
```

Comment: Did any have idea on this issue ????

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this error by adding the below entry in **java.policy file of your appserver.**. Need to edit any other policy files like was, app,client, server.

Location :

C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\lib\security\java.policy

Add this under grant block

**permission java.io.FilePermission "<< ALL FILES>>", "read";**